# How to set Lambda function name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-lambda

I am developing Lambda (NET6) and use VS2022 to Publish it to AWS.
It works but one question: When I see the Lambda functions list in AWS then I see long name (auto-generated) instead of my Lambda name "function-name" : "xx2aws"

Here is my file aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json:

```
{ 
"profile" : "aws-admin", 
"region" : "eu-west-2", 
"configuration" : "Release", 
"s3-prefix" : "XX2AWS/", 
"template" : "serverless.template", 
"template-parameters" : "", 
"s3-bucket" : "bucketxx2aws", 
"stack-name" : "xx2awscustomers", 
"function-name" : "xx2aws",
"function-description" : "xx2aws beta"
}
```

By the way: the description is applied.

I cannot rename the Lambda after it is published. How this name can be assigned to Lambda ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a default function name because it must be unique for each function. I'd expect you to supply it each time you [upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-creating-project-in-visual-studio.html#publish-to-lam) your Lambda function.

Comment: You are right, but how I can upload function with a short name? As I see: to create the function manually and then to use VS2022 for update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain your lambda [function name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-functionname) in the `serverless.template` file, instead of the `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` file.

```
 "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
         "FunctionName": "<Function_Name>",
         ...
       }
    ...
```